# Where is perspectiveM method in android.opengl.Matrix?

Tags: android, opengl-es, matrix, perspective

How can i call perspectiveM static method in Matrix class?
As said here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/Matrix.html

Сode completion suggests me frustumM, invertM, length, multiplyMM, multiplyMV, orthoM and others and no perspectiveM.

Details that could be important: last eclipse and java, android 2.3 as target, last sdk updates.

p.s. i know that i can tune matrix manually. it's just really interesting where method is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is api lvl 14. If you scroll down to perspectiveM on the page you linked, you'll see in faint grey writing the api level where the method was included from:

[image]

Comment: Oh, really it is. Answer was quiet simple)On wide screen browser placed API-mark far from method description.
Thanks a lot!